# Imaging directly into USB drive

Tags: linux, image, usb

I need to image my Raspberry Pi into a USB drive. I have tried using

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdb of=raspbian.img
```

, intending to paste it into my USB. However my SD card does not have enough space for the image. Is there a way to image directly into a USB drive?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the usb plugged into the Pi and mounted, you should be able to just do this:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdb of=[Path/to/Usb/Stick/]raspbian.img
```

Make sure you use the `sync` command after this to ensure that everything has actually been copied.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo dd if=path_to_img/x.img of=dev/sdx bs=1M &&sync` (`/dev/sdx` is the device node of the USB stick )

USB stick is normally unmounted when writing with `dd` so run `umount` if the stick is mounted ...
http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/663802/do-i-have-to-unmount-the-drive-when-using-dd-command

to create a full disk image (dd the pis SD card) see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/disk_cloning#Create_disk_image

Comment: Not quite. This works for copying a disk image to the usb drive. The OP wants to create an image of their SD card and copy it to a usb drive, likely for backup purposes.

Comment: Yeah, take a look at your command again. It is taking an image file as input and writing it to the USB. Like I said, OP wants to create an image file from their SD card and copy it to their USB drive.

Comment: Also, your arch link is broken.